# extending a core block doesn't work inside the editor

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

i want to extend the group core block, and add to it a rotate inline style. i read and use the hooks. when i add the rotate it is saved and display correctly in the front. But nothing is changed in the editor even though i have a function to update the attribute.

this is my code for the edit part to extend the core group block:

```
const testingAdvancedControls = wp.compose.createHigherOrderComponent(

(BlockEdit) => {

    return (props) => {

        // prepare all the variables needed 

        //const { post_id, block_count } = this.props; 

        const { Fragment } = wp.element;

        const {
            PanelBody,
            RangeControl,
        } = wp.components;

        const { InspectorAdvancedControl, InspectorControls, ColorPalette } = wp.blockEditor;

        const { attributes, setAttributes, isSelected, post_id, block_count, clientId, context } = props;


        //functions 

        const updateRotate = (newR) => {
            setAttributes({ rotate: (newR === undefined ? '' : newR) });
        }

        return (

            <Fragment>
                <BlockEdit {...props} />
                {isSelected &&
                    <InspectorControls>

                        {isSelected && (props.name == 'core/group') &&

                            <PanelBody title={__('test rotate', 'testing')}
                                initialOpen={false}>

                                <RangeControl
                                    label={__('Rotate', 'testing')}
                                    value={attributes.rotate}
                                    onChange={updateRotate}
                                    min={-50}
                                    max={50}
                                    step={0.1}
                                    help={__('Rotate the group', 'testing')}
                                    allowReset={true}
                                    initialPosition={0}
                                />

                            </PanelBody>
                        }

                    </InspectorControls>

                }

            </Fragment>

        )

    }

}, 'testingAdvancedControls'

);

 wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'editor.BlockEdit',
    'gutrs/add-testing-controls',
    testingAdvancedControls
);
```

why the rotation doesn't displayed inside the editor? any idea? if i give the rotete attribute a value in the editor it is passed to the front end but nothing in the editor.

any ideas?

Comment: Do you actually compile your JS? Your lack of imports and the use of the `wp.` global object suggests that you are trying to use JSX without compiling. That will not work.

Comment: obviously! the imports are at the start of the file, and i use more hooks. this is just the "edit part" because the issue is: nothing is changing in the editor.

Comment: so i got a good answer at: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75799795/extending-a-core-block-doesnt-work-inside-the-editor/75808097#75808097)

Comment: Its not obvious and you are not having any imports in this file you are showing here.